# Creating sub slides in presentation file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I have to describe my idea with a presentation file (pptx). My presentation cannot exceed 20 slides, but I want to add some extra slides with some details and show them to listeners only if they need to see details and so it is possible details slide will not be shown. As I said before,I can not add details slides directly to presentation, because it reaches its slide number limit.

Is there any way to create some slides that will be shown in specific states, when I need to describe more details?

Comment: Having them after the end of the presentation so you can jump to them if needed is not an option?

Comment: Why not add notes to the slides and distribute them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the presentation to display in Kiosk mode.  When you do this, random clicks/keystrokes won't cause the presentation to move forward/backward.

Then add a Previous/Next button, either on each slide or on a shared master; it can be visible or not, your choice, but it's something you'll click to advance to the next slide/go back to the previous slide.

Finally add animations that cause your extra material to appear.  For example, suppose you want a table of data to appear (say it's the data that a graph represents).  Add an Appear animation to the table shape, make it a trigger animation and have it appear on click of the graph.  In use, you could then click the graph to make the table appear ... but only if you want to see it.